# UV mapping. Follow Active Quads break UV island

Tags: uv

1. Unwrap object
2. After applying Follow Quads the island is breaks. All vertices are merged.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I think Follow Active Quads only works for quads, which is why those parts of your mesh were left in their original positions. They're not quads. One solution might be to add extra geometry so that your model is all quads, unwrap it, then dissolve the extra geometry when you're done.